# google scripts to firebase script authentication exception

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-firestore

i keep getting the error "Exception: Invalid argument: key (line 39, file "Auth")" when trying to run the code, i am sure that the client mail, Key, ID and sheetID are correct, however, i keep getting this exception everytime and i can't find any documentation on it.
here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  
   var email = "email";
   var key = "key";
   var projectId = "projectid";
   var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetID");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  
  var sheetLR = sheet.getLastRow(); 
  var sheetLC = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
  var sourceDataSR = 1;
  
  var sourceRange = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheetLR-sourceDataSR+1,sheetLC);
  
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  var sourceLen = sourceData.length;
  
  var data = {};
  var scores = {};
  
  for (var i=0;i<sourceLen;i++){
       
       scores = {
    ajan20:sourceData[i][3],
    bFeb20:sourceData[i][4],
    cMar20:sourceData[i][5],
    dApr20:sourceData[i][6],
    eMay20:sourceData[i][7],
    fJun20:sourceData[i][8],
    gJul20:sourceData[i][9],
    hAug20:sourceData[i][10],
    iSep20:sourceData[i][11],
    jOct20:sourceData[i][12],
    kNov20:sourceData[i][13],
    lDec20:sourceData[i][14],
    mJan21:sourceData[i][15],
    nFeb21:sourceData[i][16],
    oMar21:sourceData[i][17],
    pApr21:sourceData[i][18],
    qMay21:sourceData[i][19],
    rJun21:sourceData[i][20],
    sJul21:sourceData[i][21],
    tAug21:sourceData[i][22],
    uSep21:sourceData[i][23],
    wOct21:sourceData[i][24],
    xNov21:sourceData[i][25],
    yDec21:sourceData[i][26],
    zJan22:sourceData[i][27]
    };
    
     var Name = sourceData[i][2];
  
      sourceData[Name] = {
      aMale68KG:sourceData[i][0],
      bCountry:sourceData[i][1],
      cName:Name,
      dScores:scores
    };
       firestore.createDocument("name",sourceData);  
  }  
  }
```

Comment: Which version of the library are you using? [Documentation here](https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript)

Comment: The latest version is 32, and the README shows the format the key needs to be in.

Comment: Sorry, i found the solution, looks like it needed all the key with the double quotes inclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, you have to keep the entire key, with `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY` and `END PRIVATE KEY`.

```
var key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n your service account private key \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

Hope it will answer your problem.

Comment: I have it all already this does not seems to be the problem

Comment: did you solved somehow?

Comment: I suggest test the scenario that your private key is directly written in code .
This error indicates you r private key is wrong .
I met this error because i paste the key in setting > ScriptProperty 
I fixed this after i use PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty() to save my key .
it wont shown ant \n  in setting > scriptProperty  for OK case